# Powershell sorting files by name containing datestamp

Tags: powershell, sorting, datetime, filenames

Just stuck at the problem with sorting of files.
There are hosts that generates statistic files daily and later these files downloaded to the server.On the server they are processed by Powershell script which loads them into Excel, each file to separate sheet with the name of that file.

File names are in `N_DDMMYYYY.txt` format, where `N` stands for host's number, underscore and a date stamp.

Usually files are downloaded everyday so no problem with sorting them by creation date on the server, but initially or due to some problems all saved host's files could be downloaded at once so the creation date is the same for all (100+) files.

How these files' names could be sorted in powershell so script would source them to Excel chronologically?

Now files are sorted first by host's number then by day - like that:

```
1_01032023.txt
1_01042023.txt
1_01052023.txt 
1_01062023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_02052023.txt
```

So I need the result of sorting like that:

```
1_01032023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_04032023.txt 
1_05032023.txt
...
1_01042023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_03042023.txt
```

Looks like first I need to get a substring `DDMMYYYY` then sort it like date not an integer but stuck at that point.

Searched all stackoverflow and read all in MS powershell site concerning sort-object and sort command but still couldn't figure out that sorting function.

Comment: the date format for strings and file names should always be `YYYYMMDD`. That way it'll automatically be sorted. People have been using it for naming files for decades. `DDMMYYYY` is a terrible way to name files

Comment: Good point, @phuclv 
Will check with the developers about changing it to YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: See also ISO-8601 and RFC-3339. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339 Is there enough information known to identify the "new" files and rename them to something usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and a calculated property to sort the files.  Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <file_location> |
    Sort-Object {$_.Name -match '_(?<Day>\d{2})(?<Month>\d{2})(?<Year>\d{4})\.';"$($matches.Year)$($matches.Month)$($matches.Day)"}
```

For your example file names, this would give the output:

```
1_01032023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_01042023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_01052023.txt
1_02052023.txt
1_01062023.txt
```

This is in order of oldest at the top, newest at the bottom, but you can swap that by adding `-Descending` to the `Sort-Object` cmdlet:

`Sort-Object {$_.Name -match '_(?<Day>\d{2})(?<Month>\d{2})(?<Year>\d{4})\.';"$($matches.Year)$($matches.Month)$($matches.Day)"} -Descending`

**EDIT:**
If you have a list of filenames that include non-matching ones, the code still sorts the list with all the non-matching ones appearing first in the order they are read and the matches appearing next in the expected date order (or the opposite, if you used `-Descending`).  So for a list sorted like this in Windows:

```
1_234.txt
1_01032023.txt
1_01052023.txt
1_01062023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_02052023.txt
1-ABC123.txt
12-XY-34.txt
A1B2C3D4.txt
ABC-123.txt
```

PowerShell reads the list in this order:

```
1-ABC123.txt  
12-XY-34.txt  
1_01032023.txt
1_01042023.txt
1_01052023.txt
1_01062023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_02052023.txt
1_234.txt     
A1B2C3D4.txt  
ABC-123.txt
```

And the above code outputs this:

```
1-ABC123.txt  
12-XY-34.txt  
1_234.txt     
A1B2C3D4.txt  
ABC-123.txt   
1_01032023.txt
1_02032023.txt
1_01042023.txt
1_02042023.txt
1_01052023.txt
1_02052023.txt
1_01062023.txt
```

So you do end up with non-matching files in the output.  If this is likely (probably not in the original scenario) and undesirable, then you'd need to filter those out.

Comment: Thanks @boxdog your solution is clear and starightforward, worked like a charm.

Comment: What happens if there is a filename in the directory that does not `-match` the pattern?

Comment: @lit I've updated the answer to show what happens with a mix of matching and non-matching files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to:

- get the date from the filename (without extension)
- then, cast it to date object
- finally, sort the folder by the date

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\test" | Sort-Object { [datetime]::parseexact([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name.Split('_')[1]), 'ddMMyyyy', $null) }
```

[image: demo]